# Precompiling Assets with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm pushing changes to Heroku and I get ...

> rake aborted!
>   could not connect to server: Connection refused
>   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

When I consult the Heroku documentation [Here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting), it tells me I need to "configure a nonexistent database in your local config/database.yml" I'm not sure how to create a "nonexistent database"? I'm a beginner and would appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

On Heroku, you **must** set this line in your config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

> For faster asset precompiles, you can partially load your application
>   by setting config.assets.initialize_on_precompile to false in
>   config/application.rb, though in that case templates cannot see
>   application objects or methods. **Heroku requires this to be false.**

Comment: need to commit an app after added about this line.

Answer (score 0):

It means put in the name of a database that doesn't actually exist in your local dev environment. Then try and run `rake assets:precompile`

You're simulating the same scenario locally (an unavailable db).

Are you using Devise in this app? It had a [known issue similar to this](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/474). You may want to update that gem.

Comment: I saw that issue as well, but I'm not using Devise.
Do I need to put anything in the db that doesn't exist? Currently I have one for development, test and production like... 
  development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It seems that for some reason the DATABASE_URL environment variable is not set at the time of asset precompilation. A workaround is to set the DATABASE_URL in the production.rb file.
`ENV["DATABASE_URL"] = <your db url>`
That should fix the problem.