# Failing to push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am attempting to push my rails 3.2.12 app to heroku, which is configured with a postgres database. The first time I ran `git push heroku master` I received the below error.

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

After some troubleshooting I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990049/precompiling-assets-with-rails-3-1) post and put the following line in my `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I then ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` to begin populating the heroku database and received the following error:

```
Running rake db:create attached to terminal... up, run.4115
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
/app/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

Funny enough, line 5 of application.rb was the previous line I added:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Lastly, I noticed that I can't start the database locally with the above line in my application.rb file - I receive the following error:

```
config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
```

This issue seems like a catch 22. How can I deploy to heroku without altering the application.rb file as well as run it on my local server?

Comment: Are you sure you added `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`  in the right place? You can make sure by moving this line to after any `conf.<anything>` in the application.rb

Comment: It was right after `require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)` and `require 'rails/all'`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` is in the correct place like this:

```
module YourApplicationName
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Make sure to restart everything.

Also, if the above doesn't work, a temporary work around would be to change your `Gemfile` to:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then run `bundle install --without production`

Heroku does not recommend using a different database for development and production. However This will work and I have used it many times to get up and running easily

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it was in the wrong place. However, when I moved it to correct place (and at the very end of `class Application Rails::Application`) I receive the following error when running `git push heroku master` : `rake aborted! /tmp/build_11aq1x9l9kxod/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required` - however, the application now runs on my local server. May be worth noting that I have Twitter Bootstrap installed as well

Comment: Good, glad I could at least get you started in the right direction. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

to "config/application.rb" and uploaded my project to heroku, it got uploaded without any errors and its not working, even rake commands are not working on heroku.

I found on this article on heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline
which says add

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

to your **config/application.rb** then its working properly. It is precompiling properly when tested with "rake assets:precompile" on my computer . And my project got uploaded properly and showing things soo coool.